# cloud sql unable to connect to app engine during deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

App Engine : Flexible

CloudSQL : 2nd Gen

Framework : Node.js

Node lib: mysql

I am seeing this error after I deploy :

```
2016/10/29 11:38:03 listenInstance: "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:38:03 Remove("/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb") error: remove /cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb: no such file or directory

2016/10/29 11:38:03 Open socket for "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb" at "/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:38:03 Socket prefix: /cloudsql

2016/10/29 11:39:20 listenInstance: "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:39:20 Remove("/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb") error: remove /cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb: no such file or directory

2016/10/29 11:39:20 Open socket for "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb" at "/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:39:20 Socket prefix: /cloudsql
```

app.js :

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    multipleStatements: true,
    user: config.get('MYSQL_USER'),
    password: config.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    database: config.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
    socketPath: "/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"
});
```

app.yaml :

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"
```

I am not sure what is causing this problem.

I also did ssh into the vm to check and I can see that /cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb is existing.

Please help

Thanks in advance,
timecatcher